# Request for more information on ASM OPCodes

Tags: bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

I am learning ASM framework for Byte Code instrumentation and wrote couple of examples to achieve the same.I saw that in most of the examples JVM OPCodes are  used for ex:DUP,AASTORE,LSTORE etc but looking at the javadocs of ASM Opcodes i don't see any proper documentation for different OPcodes

for ex

AALOAD

static final int AALOAD

DUP

static final int DUP

This javadoc link http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/Opcodes.html gives the list of opcodes available but doesn't clearly describe why/when each opcode is used.I understand that these are nothing but JVM opcodes, but is there a location where i can get more details on when/why these opcodes should be used??

I am currently using ASMIFIER to get an idea of how BYTECODE representation of my code which i am supposed to inject should look like ,but better understanding of OPCodes will help me in getting better understanding of the BYTECode which i have to inject.

Thanks

VishwanathB

Comment: You should accept answers to your previous questions.

Comment: I recently started using stackoverflow to ask question so yet to get accustomed to some stuff :) ..I just accepted your answer to previous question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to find out what the opcodes do, just read "[The Java Virtual Machine Instruction Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html)" chapter of JVM specification.

If you want to find out how to chose sequences of instructions to do what you want, well, that's just programming.

Comment: Thank you.Will have look at it.